# Moment generating function of a Weibull distribution and root finding heavy and light tailed case

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, weibull-distribution, moment-generating-function, numerics

I consider the equation $M_x(v)=1+(1+\beta)\mu$ and I need to find the solution $v>0$ such that the equation is  fulfilled.

For this example I consider the moment generating function $M_X(v)$ of a Weibull distribution.

The MGF is given by:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{v^n\lambda^n}{n!}\Gamma(1+\frac{n}{k})
$$
We consider $k>1$ (shape  parameter), scale I will consider $\lambda=1$. Moreover $\beta=0.3$, How to find the solution $v>0$?

I have proceeded in the next way:

With the next R code

```r
scale <- 1
shape <- 1.5
beta  <- 0.3
## I have defined the MGF for the Weibull distribution, fixing     
## nmax=150 since It cannot be infinity  

mgfw <- function(x){
  nmax <- 150
  scale <- scale
  shape <- shape
  suma <- 0
  for(n in 0:nmax){
    suma <- suma + ((x^n)*((scale)^n))*gamma(1+(n/shape))/factorial(n)
  }
  return(suma)
}

curve(mgfw, from = 0, 10, ylim = c(0.8 , 1.4), xlim = c(0, 0.6))

mu <- (scale)*gamma(1+(1/shape))

# c <- (1 + beta ) * lambda*mu 
fun2 <- function(x) 1+x*(1+beta)*mu
x <- seq(0, 1, length.out = 100)
y <- fun2(x)

curve(mgfw, 0, 0.3, main="Adjustment Coefficient")
curve(fun2, from = 0, 1, add = TRUE)

#### Computation of the root
library(rootSolve)
r <- uniroot.all(function(x) mgfw(x)-fun2(x),c(0.10,0.47))
r
```

But I am not sure if it is ok, since I have truncated the infinite sum. Is ok my root finding computation?

This case corresponds to the Heavy tailed case, i.e shape larger than 1, when shape smaller than $1$, how to prove that the MGF doesn´t exists?

Comment: Show that the series does not converge for any $v > 0$; Stirling's approximation may be helpful here.  Basically you want to show that $\Gamma(1+n/k)/n!$ grows faster than any $v^n$ can shrink (when $k < 1$.)